# No Detections while running Yolov2 with TensorFlow Lite in Android

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, object-detection-api, yolo

I am trying to run `yolov2` with `TensorFlow Lite` in `Android`. I have integrated `Yolo v2` in Android but it is not detecting any images. In order to user `YoLo v2` model in Android, I have followed following steps:

1. Downloaded weights using `curl https://pjreddie.com/media/files/yolov2-tiny.weights -o yolov2-tiny.weights`
2. Downloaded config file using `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pjreddie/darknet/master/cfg/yolov2-tiny.cfg -o yolov2-tiny.cfg`
3. Downloaded labels file `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pjreddie/darknet/master/data/coco.names -o label.txt`
   Converted weights to tensor flow protocol buffer using `flow --model yolov2-tiny.cfg --load yolov2-tiny.weights --savepb`
4. Converted tensor flow buffers to tensor flow lite using `tflite_convert --graph_def_file='/home/mustansar/Softwares/darkflow/built_graph/yolov2-tiny.pb'  --output_file='/home/mustansar/Softwares/darkflow/built_graph/yolov2-tiny.lite'  --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF --output_format=TFLITE --input_shape=1,416,416,3 --input_array=input --output_array=output`

In the end I have two files `yolov2-tiny.lite` and `yolov2-tiny.meta`. In Android I am using dependency: `implementation('org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly') { changing = true }`

I have loaded model and processing the image as :

Detector Class:

```
@Override
  public List<Recognition> recognizeImage(final Bitmap bitmap) {
    convertBitmapToByteBuffer(bitmap);

    tfLite.run(imgData, outputLocations);

    return findRecognitionsUsingTensorExample();
  }
```

**findRecognitionUsingTensorExample()**

```
public ArrayList<Recognition> findRecognitionsUsingTensorExample() {
    float[][][] output = outputLocations[0];
//
    // Find the best detections.
    final PriorityQueue<Recognition> pq =
            new PriorityQueue<Recognition>(
                    1,
                    new Comparator<Recognition>() {
                      @Override
                      public int compare(final Recognition lhs, final Recognition rhs) {
                        // Intentionally reversed to put high confidence at the head of the queue.
                        return Float.compare(rhs.getConfidence(), lhs.getConfidence());
                      }
                    });

    for (int y = 0; y < gridHeight; ++y) {
      for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; ++x) {
        for (int b = 0; b < NUM_BOXES_PER_BLOCK; ++b) {
          final int offset =
                  (gridWidth * (NUM_BOXES_PER_BLOCK * (NUM_CLASSES + 5))) * y
                          + (NUM_BOXES_PER_BLOCK * (NUM_CLASSES + 5)) * x
                          + (NUM_CLASSES + 5) * b;

          if(offset >= 416 || offset + 1 >= 416) continue;

          final float xPos = (x + expit(output[y][x][offset + 0])) * blockSize;
          final float yPos = (y + expit(output[y][x][offset + 1])) * blockSize;

          final float w = (float) (Math.exp(output[y][x][offset + 2]) * ANCHORS[2 * b + 0]) * blockSize;
          final float h = (float) (Math.exp(output[y][x][offset + 3]) * ANCHORS[2 * b + 1]) * blockSize;

          final RectF rect =
                  new RectF(
                          Math.max(0, xPos - w / 2),
                          Math.max(0, yPos - h / 2),
                          Math.min(INP_IMG_WIDTH - 1, xPos + w / 2),
                          Math.min(INP_IMG_HEIGHT - 1, yPos + h / 2));
          final float confidence = expit(output[y][x][offset + 4]);

          int detectedClass = -1;
          float maxClass = 0;

          final float[] classes = new float[NUM_CLASSES];
          for (int c = 0; c < NUM_CLASSES; ++c) {
            classes[c] = output[x][y][offset + 5 + c];
          }
          softmax(classes);

          for (int c = 0; c < NUM_CLASSES; ++c) {
            if (classes[c] > maxClass) {
              detectedClass = c;
              maxClass = classes[c];
            }
          }

          final float confidenceInClass = maxClass * confidence;
          if (confidenceInClass > THRESHOLD) {
            LOGGER.i(
                    "%s (%d) %f %s", LABELS[detectedClass], detectedClass, confidenceInClass, rect);
            pq.add(new Recognition("" + offset, LABELS[detectedClass], confidenceInClass, rect));
          }
        }
      }
    }
    final ArrayList<Recognition> recognitions = new ArrayList<Recognition>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(pq.size(), MAX_RESULTS); ++i) {
      recognitions.add(pq.poll());
    }

    return recognitions;
  }
```

From `yolov2-tiny.meta`, I have used configuration i.e. `classes=80`, `threshold=0.6`, `image size = 416x416`, `labels` from file and `anchors` from meta file. I am unable to find the missing element.

> Can anyone please guide why objects are not being detected?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run the TF model before convert it to tflite? You can also simply tried to run the tflite model with python first. Those will give a hint where the problem come from.

Comment: What script to run to verify tflite model using python?